# How to optimally organize data analysis with different Date granularity

Tags: r, date, ggplot2, analytics, lubridate

I am analyzing data for a client and I am building a Shiny app to showcase my graphs.
The original time granularity of this data is very granular as it is raw data and it is in UTC to the second. ie: `2019-12-16 17:07:40`
I started my analysis at a weekly granularity using the `cut` function:

```
Signup_Table_Weekly <- User_Info[ , c("userID", "Signup_Date", "Device")]
Signup_Table_Weekly$Signup_Date <- cut(as.Date(Signup_Table$Signup_Date), "week")
```

I have the feeling this is not optimized at all because I now want to analyze the same data at a monthly granularity and I find myself having to replicate the same chunk of code and modify the parameter `"week"` in `cut` to `"month"`, ending up with multiple dataframes:

```
Signup_Table_Monthly <- User_Info[ , c("userID", "Signup_Date", "Device")]
Signup_Table_Monthly$Signup_Date <- cut(as.Date(Signup_Table$Signup_Date), "month")
```

Any advice on the proper method? Should I do all my analysis with very granular raw dates and only aggregate in my `ggplot` X axis graph for the Date ?

Comment: If you're building a Shiny app, my approach would be to make the data.frame a reactive and then instead of hard coding "week" or "month", replace it with a reactiveVal or input that would update the calculation

Comment: The issue with this approach is that the data I am dealing with is quite granular and the volume is quite big. So if I keep the date as `2019-12-16 17:07:40` the calculations are going to be very consuming. Furthermore I am sometimes doing `group_by` date and with this granularity it does not make sense